# I have the following problem when using autocomplete_fields field under django3.2

Tags: python, django

The following problems will occur:

[image: screenshot]

When I use the version below django3.2, everything is normal. I don't know if this is my problem?

And django will raise the following error:

```
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\easyshow\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\autocomplete.py", line 61, in process_request
        app_label = request.GET['app_label']
    File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\easyshow\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 78, in __getitem__
        raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'app_label'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\easyshow\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
    File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\easyshow\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\easyshow\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 250, in wrapper
        return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\easyshow\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\easyshow\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\easyshow\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 232, in inner
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\easyshow\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 417, in autocomplete_view
        return AutocompleteJsonView.as_view(admin_site=self)(request)
    File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\easyshow\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
        return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\easyshow\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\easyshow\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\autocomplete.py", line 20, in get
        self.term, self.model_admin, self.source_field, to_field_name = self.process_request(request)
    File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\easyshow\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\autocomplete.py", line 65, in process_request
        raise PermissionDenied from e

django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied
```

Comment: What was the previous Django version that this worked for you?

Comment: The version I am using is django3.2. Because of this problem, I have to downgrade the version to 3.2 or less

Comment: Not exactly what I'm asking. Does this work for you in Django 3.1?

Comment: yes,There is no problem under 3.1

Comment: And no warnings, like deprecation warnings or any other type of warning?

Answer (score 3):

Run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32659

Answer (score 1):

It is a caching problem.
Go to your django shell: `python manage.py shell`

Then

```py
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.clear()
```

Refresh your form on the browser and you're good to go!